# How to copy rage of rows in google sheets according to the range mentioned in sheet1

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In sheet1 there are 2 columns.

in first column there is number 6 and in second column there is a number 20.

This means, all the data in Sheet2 from row 6 to 20 has to get copied in Sheet3.

So in the future, if we change number in sheet1, the data should flow according to those numbers

Could somebody help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

### Apps Script features the method [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination), the documentation contains a sample:

```
// The code below copies the first 5 columns over to the 6th column.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 5);
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 6));
```

You can adapt this sample to your question but performing two modifications:

1. Instead of copying the range to the range in the same sheet - defined two different sheets and copy it from the one to the other
2. When defining the range with the method [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) instead of assigning to the parameters static numbers, retrieve the values dynamically from your spreadsheet.

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet3 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  //adapt the ranges to the real cells contianing the row information
  var startRow = sheet1.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var endRow = sheet1.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var rowNumber = endRow-startRow+1;
  var rangeToCopy = sheet2.getRange(startRow, 1, rowNumber, sheet2.getLastRow());
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet3.getRange(startRow, 1));
}
```